# How to output a shell command using echo

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to format a shell out

```
str="set @face_date = '20130612'
```

The below code returns the out as '20130612'

```
echo $str |  cut -d '=' -f2
```

But the following code is not working

```
echo "face_date:=TO_DATE("$str | cut -d '=' -f2"),'YYYY/MM/DD');"
```

Expected Result:

```
face_date:= to_date('2013-06-12','YYYY/MM/DD');
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You're nesting double-quotes inside other double-quotes. Try escaping them with backslashes.

Comment: perhaps try an embedded `echo` in backquote. not sure how newlines are handled though. except for that should work. like `echo "face_date:=TO_DATE("\`echo $str | cut -d '=' -f2\`"),'YYYY/MM/DD');"` disclaimer: haven't tried and i seldom use Unix-land shells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more way,

```
echo "face_date:=TO_DATE($(echo $str | cut -d '=' -f2)),'YYYY/MM/DD');"
```

This will produce following output.

```
face_date:=TO_DATE( '20130612'),'YYYY/MM/DD');
```

or you can use

```
str1=$(echo $str |  cut -d '=' -f2)
echo "face_date:=TO_DATE($(echo ${str1:0:6}-${str1:6:2}-${str1:8:3}),'YYYY/MM/DD');"
```

for following output

```
face_date:=TO_DATE('2013-06-12','YYYY/MM/DD');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
echo "face_date:=TO_DATE($(cut -d '=' -f2 <<< "$str")),'YYYY/MM/DD');"
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
face_date:=TO_DATE( '20130612'),'YYYY/MM/DD');
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution) can help you. You need to include your command in ` (ASCII #96) in order to get executed. Perhaps that question is a better fit [here](https://superuser.com/) though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either escape the inner double quotes, or surround in `$()` or ``:

```
echo "face_date:=TO_DATE($("$str | cut -d '=' -f2")),'YYYY/MM/DD');"
```

or simply get rid of all the `pipes` and `cut`, just do:

```
echo "face_date:=TO_DATE(${str##* }),'YYYY/MM/DD');"
```